# RecyclerView with Header Getting Duplicate Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, activeandroid

I have a recyclerview list of items and in the adapter, I have a button for adding an item as favorite to an `active android` database like below code:

```
viewholder.favoriteWP_IV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Favorites favorites = new Favorites(); // Model class for db crud

            favorites.setFavoritesId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            favorites.setLargeImgURL(pixaImages.getLargeImgURL());
            favorites.setPreviewImgURL(pixaImages.getPreviewImgURL());
            favorites.setImageId(favorites.getImageId());

            favorites.save();
            Log.d(TAG, "Fav_id:\t" + favorites.getId());
            Log.d(TAG, "Favorites Id:\t" + favorites.getFavoritesId());


            //TODO: 6/13/2018 Fix Duplicate Favorite WP
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added to Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

and in my `FavoritesActivity`, I have retrieved all the items and shown them in a recyclerview like below code:

```
 public List<Favorites> getAllFavorites() {
    return new Select()
            .all()
            .from(Favorites.class)
            .orderBy("favorites_id ASC")
            .execute();
}

private void getFavorites() {
    favsRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    favsRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    AdapterHeaderItem headerItem = new AdapterHeaderItem();
    headerItem.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.drawer_header_trimmed);
    headerItem.setHeaderTitle("you can toggle through your favorite wallpapers using the wallpaper widget on your home screen");
    objectList.add(headerItem);

    //itemsList = getAllFavorites();
    Favorites favorites = new Favorites();
    for (int i = 0; i < getAllFavorites().size(); i++) {
        favorites.setFavoritesId(getAllFavorites().get(i).getFavoritesId());
        favorites.setLargeImgURL(getAllFavorites().get(i).getLargeImgURL());
        favorites.setPreviewImgURL(getAllFavorites().get(i).getPreviewImgURL());
        favorites.setImageId(getAllFavorites().get(i).getImageId());
        Log.d(TAG, "All Favs Ids:\t" + getAllFavorites().get(i).getFavoritesId());
        objectList.add(favorites);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Favorites List Size:\t" + objectList.size());

    adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(this, objectList);
    favsRV.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

The problem here is that the item clicked on to be saved is not the one actually saved `and` when the `list has multiple items`, it retrieves duplicate copies of same item.

Previously, my adapter wasn't having a header and it was working fine but when I added the header to adapter, I had to change from `List<Favorites> to List<Object>` to enable me add the header items to the view.

In my activity, I have retrieved all the records while using old adapter code by this line `itemsList = getAllFavorites();` but with the new adapter code, I have to use an object to store items in list.

I have tried this `Favorites favs = (Favorites) itemsList = getAllFavorites();` but the app crashed, only other option I had was to do this and save in object list:

```
    Favorites favorites = new Favorites();
    for (int i = 0; i < getAllFavorites().size(); i++) {
        favorites.setFavoritesId(getAllFavorites().get(i).getFavoritesId());
        favorites.setLargeImgURL(getAllFavorites().get(i).getLargeImgURL());
        favorites.setPreviewImgURL(getAllFavorites().get(i).getPreviewImgURL());
        favorites.setImageId(getAllFavorites().get(i).getImageId());
        Log.d(TAG, "All Favs Ids:\t" + getAllFavorites().get(i).getFavoritesId());
        objectList.add(favorites);
    }
```

Here's my model class:

```
import com.activeandroid.Model;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Table;

@Table(name = "favorites")
public class Favorites extends Model{

  @Column(name = "favorites_id")
  public String favoritesId;

  @Column(name = "image_id")
  public int imageId;

  @Column(name = "large_img_url")
  public String largeImgURL;

  @Column(name = "preview_img")
  public String previewImgURL;

  public Favorites() { }

  public Favorites(String favoritesId, int imageId, String largeImgURL, String previewImgURL) {
      this.favoritesId = favoritesId;
      this.imageId = imageId;
      this.largeImgURL = largeImgURL;
      this.previewImgURL = previewImgURL;
  }

  public String getFavoritesId() {
      return favoritesId;
  }

  public void setFavoritesId(String favoritesId) {
      this.favoritesId = favoritesId;
  }

  public int getImageId() {
      return imageId;
  }

  public void setImageId(int imageId) {
      this.imageId = imageId;
  }

  public String getLargeImgURL() {
      return largeImgURL;
  }

  public void setLargeImgURL(String largeImgURL) {
      this.largeImgURL = largeImgURL;
  }

  public String getPreviewImgURL() {
      return previewImgURL;
  }

  public void setPreviewImgURL(String previewImgURL) {
      this.previewImgURL = previewImgURL;
  }
}
```

but this code block gives me for a list of three items, one item duplicated three times. I think it's because of the change in code. The adapter works well but in activity, I am fetching wrong results.

Here's my adapter code:

```
public class FavoritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = FavoritesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context context;
private List<Object> itemsList;

public static final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
public static final int ITEMS_VIEW = 1;

public FavoritesAdapter(Context context, List<Object> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == HEADER_VIEW) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.app_adapter_header_layout, parent, false);
        return new AdapterHeaderItemViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == ITEMS_VIEW) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.favorites_item_layout, parent, false);
        return new FavoritesViewHolder(view);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No matching viewTypes");
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof AdapterHeaderItemViewHolder) {
        AdapterHeaderItem header = (AdapterHeaderItem) itemsList.get(position);
        ((AdapterHeaderItemViewHolder) holder).headerTitleTV.setText(header.getHeaderTitle());

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(header.getHeaderIcon())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.drawer_header_trimmed)
                .into(((AdapterHeaderItemViewHolder) holder).headerIconIV);

    } else if (holder instanceof FavoritesViewHolder) {
        final Favorites favorites = (Favorites) itemsList.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(favorites.getLargeImgURL())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(((FavoritesViewHolder) holder).favoriteWPImg);

        ((FavoritesViewHolder) holder).removeTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Adapter VH Posn:\t" + holder.getAdapterPosition());

                String fav_id = favorites.getFavoritesId();
                Log.d(TAG, "Favorites+id:\t" + fav_id);
                removeAtPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition(), fav_id);
            }
        });

        ((FavoritesViewHolder) holder).previewTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent previewIntent = new Intent(context, PreviewWallPaperActivity.class);
                previewIntent.putExtra("fav_id", favorites.getFavoritesId());
                previewIntent.putExtra("large_url", favorites.getLargeImgURL());
                previewIntent.putExtra("preview_url", favorites.getPreviewImgURL());
                context.startActivity(previewIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}

private void removeAtPosition(int position, String id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "id in method:\t" + id);
    new Delete()
            .from(Favorites.class)
            .where("favorites_id=?", id)
            .execute();
    Log.d(TAG, "Favorite Removed from db");
    itemsList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemsList.size());

    Toast.makeText(context, "Removed From Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return HEADER_VIEW;
    return ITEMS_VIEW;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

}
```

I think the problem lies here with the loop and inserting into the adapter list:

```
itemsList = getAllFavorites();

    Favorites favorites = new Favorites();
    for (int i = 0; i < getAllFavorites().size(); i++) {
        favorites.setFavoritesId(getAllFavorites().get(i).getFavoritesId());
        favorites.setLargeImgURL(getAllFavorites().get(i).getLargeImgURL());
        favorites.setPreviewImgURL(getAllFavorites().get(i).getPreviewImgURL());
        favorites.setImageId(getAllFavorites().get(i).getImageId());
        Log.d(TAG, "All Favs Ids:\t" + getAllFavorites().get(i).getFavoritesId());
        objectList.add(favorites);
    }

    //objectList.add(itemsList); // I have tried adding the first list of Favorite model class into the adapter list but it gives `classcast exception: Model class can't be cast to ArrayList`
```

Can anyone help me understand why same item is coming multiple times? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide your adapter code ?

Comment: @gianhtran, check again

Comment: it's seem correct code, your loop to adding item list is okey, I will check again, anw, you can using objectList.addAll(itemsList)

Comment: the result log from  Log.d(TAG, "All Favs Ids:\t" + getAllFavorites().get(i).getFavoritesId()); is okey?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I have three items and it shows the correct non-duplicate ids for all three items.

Comment: and how many items display ;

Comment: All items were logged but one item displayed three times